# How do I connect a bot to Skype and Cortana?

Tags: c#, botframework

The current FAQ for the BotFramework says that you do not have to publish your bot  in the bot directory, and that it supports Skype; it doesn't list Cortana (but MS mentioned at build that it supports Cortana, so maybe the FAQ is out of date?).

Anyway -- all of the tutorials that I've seen so far make you register your bot in the bot directory to configure them -- how do you setup a normal bot that's not registered in the bot directory and connect it to services like Skype and Cortana?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new bot on dev.botframework.com, it is already automatically connected to Skype. You don't need to do anything and it can have up to <s>50</s> 100 users.

Cortana is an entirely different thing. You cannot have Cortana as a channel, like telegram or skype. (How would it even look like).

What you probably heard about is the ability to leverage Cortana's functions using a LUIS built-in app. LUIS is the language processing system for bots. Their built-in Cortana-like app will recognize stuff like "set a reminder for..." and "give me directions to...".

Comment: K48 is spot on, with the caveat that Skype does 100 users initially, and more after bot review.

Comment: Okay, but how do I build just a regular bot that isn't on the "bot store" or whatever? -- I don't want random users messaging my bot and breaking it, I just want to explore the framework and build a proof-of-concept. -- The FAQ says you don't have to register your bot to connect it to services.

Comment: Your bot by default doesn't get added to the bot directory, that's a manual step that you can choose to take after you build your bot.   You can connect to channels, at which point the visibility of the bot is up to you and the channel service you connected the Bot to.

Comment: @BrainSlugs83 don't know about Skype but on Facebook nobody can access your bot except the users you specifically approve. If you want to make it public, you need to click a few extra buttons.

Answer (score 0):

To connect your bot to Skype,Messenger,Slack..you have to register it to http://botframework.com using your microsoft account,get an AppId,AppSecret which you will put back in your web.config file (in your project).Don't forget also that you need to publish your project to any cloud based hosting like Azure.